# Switch row background based on date on Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a column that store the date and I try to implement a conditional formatting custom formula that switch background color of an entire row (or multiple cells of a row) if the day is odd or even.

Here is a coma separated value version of my sheet and what I try to achieve. Date and time are in separate columns. I can have multiple rows with the same date (different times). Rows with the same date must have the same color.

```
Date,       Time, Data
01/12/2014, 01:00, "xxxx" -> BG = X
01/12/2014, 03:00, "xxxx" -> BG = X
02/12/2014, 01:00, "xxxx" -> BG = Y
03/12/2014, 01:00, "xxxx" -> BG = X
03/12/2014, 02:00, "xxxx" -> BG = X
04/12/2014, 03:00, "xxxx" -> BG = Y
```

To compute if the day is even or odd, I wrote a simple function that return the number of days since 01/01/1970:

```
/**
 * Return the day of the year of a date or a range
 *
 * @param {date}|{Array.Array} Date or range.
 * @return The day of year.
 * @customfunction
 */
function DAYSFROM70(date) 
{
  if (date.map) {
    return date.map(DAYSFROM70);
  } else {
    if (!date instanceof Date || !date.getTime) {
      return "";
    } else {
      return Math.ceil(date.getTime() / 86400000);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the custom formula I tried to apply (note that DAYSFROm70 function is using a range as parameter), without success:

```
=ISODD(DAYSFROM70($B$2:$B$101))
```

The following formula does color cells backgrounds (but I obviously can't use that, sunday and monday are both odd):

```
=ISODD(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$101))
```

Something is wrong with my script but I can't figure out what...

Check out this spreadsheet for testing: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U49FoeMPKlvjCURsqS7GxTH62u_fTJNCcH12XFQtWVQ

Thanks for your help.

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why cant you just do: =isodd(day(A1)) ??

- select whole sheet
- click format -> conditional formatting
- from the dropdown choose "custom formula"
- in the formula box put: `=isodd(day($A1))`
- select your format (background color)
- click ok.

### edit

in your question you did not speciffy what you meant by "day is odd".

since you want to colour rows for "every other day" irrespective of day of year, month, or year you can just do (using build in functions):
`=isodd(DATEVALUE($A1))`

[please read instructions above on applying the conditional formula. You DO NOT need to use a range or array]

**DO NOT REFER TO A RANGE IN THE CONDITIONAL FORMATTING FORMULA!!** "=ISEVEN(WEEKDAY($B$2:$B$23))" <- NO!!

"=isodd(DATEVALUE($A2))" <- YES!! (where A2 is the topmost row of the range you are formatting - as written in the "range" box in the conditional formatting popup dialog)

Comment: DAY() return the day of the month, so the last day of a 31 days month will have have the same color than the next day (DAY(31/01/2014) = 31 => odd, DAY(01/02/2014) = 1 => odd)

Comment: yes, I had to find a meaning for "day is odd" and in my case weekdays and monthdays did not work because two consecutive days can be either odd or even so I choose to compute the number of days based on the timestamp. I don't understand why I do not need to use a range in my formula? I tried with a single cell and it didn't work either, with both DATEVALUE (colors everything) or DAYSFROM70 functions.

Comment: did you follow the instructions for the conditional formatting, exactly as I wrote? I have copied your (test) sheet, and followed my instructions, and the formatting is as required.

Comment: alright, got it working using DATEVALUE as you mentioned. Many thanks to you. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google Spreadsheet doesn't support dates in that format. Using your function, I get an error when trying that format, but if I remove the times from the end, it works fine.

Work around: Add the date as a custom format: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en

I got it work with: "12/1/2014 1:00:00" by setting the format:

```
Year(1930)-Month(08)-Day(05),Hour(1):Minute(1)
```

----EDIT-----

I set the conditional formatting to:

```
=ISODD(DAYSFROM70($A1))
```

I had the dates in column A, so this will change the entire row is the date is odd.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, date and time are in different columns and dates are stored as DD/MM/YYYY, so they are correctly recognised by google spreadsheet. It was just to illustrate that I can have multiple row for the same day. This is working for a single cell but not for a range. =ISODD(DAYSFROM70($B$2:$B$101))

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are in ColumnA please try Format, Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is :

```
=isodd(text($A1,"#"))
```

with formatting of choice applied to Range: A:Z (or extended as required).